# how to call to web api2 controller method from component http.post method in angular2

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

Component.ts

```
TableHeader(Id: any) {       
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let body = JSON.stringify(Id);
  var sub = this.http.post('api/Customers/GetColumnNames/', body, options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

WebApiController

```
[AcceptVerbs("Post")]
[ActionName("GetColumnNames")]
public DataSet GetColumnNames(String id) {
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  if (Convert.ToInt32(id) > 0) {
    //AccountingMethods objAcc = new AccountingMethods();
    //return ds = objAcc.GetColumnsNames("GetColumns", id);
  }
  return new DataSet();
}
```

When calling webapi controller action name .i am not getting hit

Comment: Can you just pass the id ad query string and try.

Comment: Show WebApiConfig where you configure your routes

Answer (score 0):

We are going to need some extra information:

I am assuming that you have the following WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

I would also try to

```
[Route("api/Customers/GetColumnNames")]
[HttpPost]
```

If all else fails try changing the call to

```
var sub = this.http.post('api/Customers/GetColumnNames', body, options)
.map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

The trailing slash shouldn't affect the call but it's been mentioned in the past as a problem so it might be valuable to try.

What would greatly help is for you to add the error from the browser (in chrome it's F12 for the tools and Network to see the call.